# accessing JavaScript variables in laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I have got stuck in an issue of the laravel project. I have a ticket page that display the bus name, bus destination , ticket price value from the vehicle tables of the database. Beside this there is a ticket booking template made in JavaScript that count the number and seats and give the value of count and selected seat and that page. What i want to do is to take these two value from the JavaScript variable and pass them to database of orders table as with the other value of the vehicle table that are showing. I want value of var str and var rTotal to send in database with other variables that are sending using hidden fields of form [screen shot of front end](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V6g9p.jpg)

```
@extends ('layouts.app')
@section('content')
 <div id="all">
      <div id="content">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row bar">
            <div class="col-lg-9">
              <div id="productMain" class="row">
                <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-6">
                   <div class="plane">
  <div class="cockpit">
    <h1>Please select a seat</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="exit exit--front fuselage">   
  </div>
   <form id="frmCareer" method="get" action="prjFormEvent.js">
    <strong><label id="lblRealistic">"R" Section</label></strong>   
<div id="realisticTotal"></div>
<a href="#" onclick="getValue();return false;">Get Value</a>
  <ol class="cabin fuselage">
    <li class="row row--1">
      <ol class="seats" type="A">
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="checkbox" name="chkRealistic" onclick="getRealistic()" class="checks" value="1A" id="1A" />
          <label for="1A">1A</label>
        </li>
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="checkbox" name="chkRealistic" onclick="getRealistic()" class="checks" value="1B" id="1B" />
          <label for="1B">1B</label>
        </li>
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="checkbox" name="chkRealistic" onclick="getRealistic()" class="checks" value="1C" id="1C" />
          <label for="1C">1C</label>
        </li>
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="checkbox"name="chkRealistic" onclick="getRealistic()" class="checks" value="1D" disabled id="1D" />
          <label for="1D">Occupied</label>
        </li>
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="checkbox" name="chkRealistic" onclick="getRealistic()" class="checks" value="1E" id="1E" />
          <label for="1E">1E</label>
        </li>
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="checkbox" name="chkRealistic" onclick="getRealistic()" class="checks" value="1F" id="1F" />
          <label for="1F">1F</label>
        </li>
      </ol>
    </li>
  </ol>
  <div class="exit exit--back fuselage">

  </div>
</div>
        <script>
            function getValue() {

                var checks = document.getElementsByClassName('checks');
                var str = '';

                for ( i = 0; i < 6; i++) {

                    if ( checks[i].checked === true ) {
                        str += checks[i].value + " ";
                    }

                }
                document.getElementById("lblRealfisti").innerHTML = str

            }
var getCareer = new Array();
getCareer["1A"] = 1;
getCareer["1B"] = 1;
getCareer["1C"] = 1;
getCareer["1D"] = 1;
getCareer["1E"] = 1;
getCareer["1F"] = 1;

function getRealistic()
{
    var rTotal = 0;

    var selectedRealistic = document.forms["frmCareer"]["chkRealistic"];

    for (var sel = 0; sel < selectedRealistic.length; sel++)
    {
      if (selectedRealistic[sel].checked)    
          rTotal += getCareer[selectedRealistic[sel].value]        
    }      
    document.getElementById("lblRealistic").innerHTML = rTotal+ "/9 Checked"
}
        </script>
     </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                  <div class="box">
                                          <div class="sizes">
                                            <form>
                                                  <h3>{{$product->name}}</h3>
                        <h3>{{$product->departure}}</h3>
                        <h3>{{$product->destination}}</h3>
                        <h3>{{$product->date_arrival}}</h3>
                        <h3>{{$product->price}}</h3>
                        <h3>{{$product->description}}</h3>
                        <strong><label id="lblRealisti"></label></strong>                     
                      </div>
                      <p class="price">{{$product->price}}</p>
                      <p class="text-center">
                        <form action="{{route('cart.store')}}" method="post">
                              {{ csrf_field() }}                    
                          <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{$product->id}}">
                          <input type="hidden" name="name" value="{{$product->name}}">
                          <input type="hidden" name="price" value="{{$product->price}}">
                          <input type="hidden" name="price" value="{{$product->seats}}">                     
                  <button type="submit">click me</button>
                       </form>
                      </p>

                  </div>
                  <div data-slider-id="1" class="owl-thumbs">
                    <button class="owl-thumb-item"><img src="img/detailsquare.jpg" alt="" class="img-fluid"></button>
                    <button class="owl-thumb-item"><img src="img/detailsquare2.jpg" alt="" class="img-fluid"></button>
                    <button class="owl-thumb-item"><img src="img/detailsquare3.jpg" alt="" class="img-fluid"></button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>  
              <div id="product-social" class="box social text-center mb-5 mt-5">
                <h4 class="heading-light">Show it to your friends</h4>
                <ul class="social list-inline">
                  <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="#" data-animate-hover="pulse" class="external facebook"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
                  <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="#" data-animate-hover="pulse" class="external gplus"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a></li>
                  <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="#" data-animate-hover="pulse" class="external twitter"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
                  <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="#" data-animate-hover="pulse" class="email"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>           
             <div class="container">
      <div class="container hotelbook-section">
      <div class="section-padding"></div>
        <div class="section-header">
          <h3>Book your seat</h3>
          <span>We're gonna dreams come true</span>
        </div>
            <div class="row text-center">
 @foreach($mightAlsoLike as $product)
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 mb-4">
          <div class="card">
            <img class="card-img-top" src="/img/projects/new/bus1.jpeg" alt="">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h4 class="card-title"><img src="/img/line-chart.png" alt="">&nbsp; {{ $product->departure }}</h4>
              <h4 class="card-title"><img src="/img/line-chart.png" alt="">&nbsp;{{ $product->destination }}</h4>
              <h4 class="card-title"><img src="/img/line-chart.png" alt="">&nbsp;{{ $product->date_arrival}}</h4>
              <p class="card-text"><img src="/img/coins.png" alt="">RS&nbsp;{{ $product->price }}</p>
            </div>
            <div class="card-footer">
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Book Me</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

 @endforeach 
</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    @endsection
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the two hidden fields to your form:

```
 <input type="hidden" id="str" name="str" value=""> 
 <input type="hidden" id="rTotal" name="rTotal" value="">
```

Then in your `getValue` and `getRealistic` functions set the value of the fields:

```
document.getElementById('str').value = str;
document.getElementById('rTotal').value = rTotal;
```

So you would end up with functions like:

```
function getValue() {
  var checks = document.getElementsByClassName('checks');
  var str = '';
  for ( i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    if ( checks[i].checked === true ) {
       str += checks[i].value + " ";
    }
  }
  document.getElementById("lblRealfisti").innerHTML = str
  document.getElementById('str').value = str;
}


function getRealistic() {
  var rTotal = 0;
  var selectedRealistic = document.forms["frmCareer"]["chkRealistic"];
  for (var sel = 0; sel < selectedRealistic.length; sel++) {
    if (selectedRealistic[sel].checked)    
      rTotal += getCareer[selectedRealistic[sel].value]        
    }      
  }
  document.getElementById("lblRealistic").innerHTML = rTotal+ "/9 Checked"
  document.getElementById('rTotal').value = rTotal;
}
```